# Yii2: building complex queries with Query vs ActiveRecord

Tags: php, mysql, join, yii, yii2

I have these two queries, first is written using `Active Record`, and second is custom crafted using `yii\db\Query`. In my localhost query written with Query is 2-4 miliseconds faster, but is harder to write. Also query written with AR will execute several database queries more plus SHOW CREATE TABLE ones, in total it is like 10 or 12 queries more that are executed when I do AR. Plus AR requires you to have AR model defined for every table in relations network, while if you avoid AR you will end up with less classes/files in your app.

My question is, would you use AR or would write queries with `yii\db\Query` ? AR is prettier and easier to write, but it generate so many queries, is that a problem ? I am working on a site where tables have few millions of rows and there are about 100k site visits every day.

AR query :

```
return self::find()->select('id, news_users_id')
                   ->with([
                        'newsUsers' => function ($query) {
                            $query->select(['ID', 'cmpid']);
                        },
                    ])
                   ->with([
                        'newsUsers.firme' => function ($query) {
                            $query->select(['id', 'skraceni_naziv']);
                        },
                    ])
                   ->with([
                        'newsUsers.firmeBh' => function ($query) {
                            $query->select(['id', 'skraceni_naziv']);
                        },
                    ])
                   ->with([
                        'newsUsers.firmeOstalo' => function ($query) {
                            $query->select(['id', 'skraceni_naziv']);
                        },
                    ])
                   ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
                   ->limit(6)
                   ->all();
```

Query:

```
$query = new Query;

$query->select(['club.id',
                'firme.id', 'firme.skraceni_naziv',
                'firme_bh.id', 'firme_bh.skraceni_naziv',
                'firme_ostalo.id', 'firme_ostalo.skraceni_naziv']) 

      ->from('club')
      ->innerJoin('news_users', 'club.news_users_id = news_users.ID')
      ->leftJoin('firme', 'news_users.cmpid = firme.id')
      ->leftJoin('firme_bh', 'news_users.cmpid = firme_bh.id')
      ->leftJoin('firme_ostalo', 'news_users.cmpid = firme_ostalo.id')
      ->orderBy(['club.id' => SORT_DESC])
      ->limit(6);

$command = $query->createCommand();

return $command->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, it is possible to cache your schema and avoid those "SHOW CREATE TABLE" queries. Set it using `enableSchemaCache` attribute of your `db` object.

Second, joins are not always the best way to populate related records. For example, if every entry in table A has many related entries in table B, joining B to A will result in entries from table A to be repeated. That may be a performance issue.

For this reason yii2 has `with()` and `joinWith()`. Using `with()` to get the related table will make 2 queries, but more often than not it's more efficient to do so.

Lastly, AR is an immensely convenient tool once you get the hang of it. For me, its benefits outweigh the overhead.

Answer (score 3):

First of all: ActiveRecord::find() method returns ActiveQuery instance which extends Query class. So you may do with ActiveRecord::find() everything you do with Query object.

The difference is: ActiveQuery has few extra methods including 'with' method which is not the same as 'join' method as it runs extra db requests s you have already nticed. As a result of using ActiveQuery and 'with' method you get ActiveRecord objects as a main result and its relations. In other hand Query will return only database data as arrays, so you will miss your ActiveRecord methods.

If performance is important you'd better generally use joins as it will require only one db request. But a lot of joined data could be critical for performance as well. So I believe you will need some special decision here if you get in trouble with performance.